# How to pass image to bootstrap modal window in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have photo index page, In that when I want to click a image that image will show in modal window. i have tried below code. i am not getting right output.

```
<%= render 'shared_page' %>
      <div class="widget-content">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class='datatable table-bordered table-hover'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
              <th>Address</th>              
              <th>Mobile Number</th>
              <th>Landline Number</th>
              <th>Image Type</th>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Actions</th>              
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <% @cable_photos.each do |cable| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= cable.address %></td>
                <td><%= cable.mobile_no %></td>
                <td><%= cable. phone_no %></td>
                <td><%= cable.image_type %></td>
                <td> <%= link_to image_tag cable.avatar.url(:thumb), data: {toggle: "modal",target: "#myModal", :id => cable.id } %></td> 
                <td>
                  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cable_photo_path(cable), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
                  <%= link_to cable, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger ' do %>
                    <i class='icon icon-remove'></i>
                  <% end %>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <% if params[:id].present? %>
       <% @cable = CablePhoto.find(data('id')) %>
       <%= image_tag @cable.avatar.url %>
       <% end %>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: dont query from the view. If the number of records is going to be less, render modal popups with different ids such that each modal contains the data of the row. when the link on row is clicked, its related modal will be shown. ie. if u have 10 rows, render 10 modals. when user clicks on link of 3rd row, display 3rd modal. If the number of records is going to be huge, send a ajax and populate the modal body with the data fetched.

Comment: @user2310209 - Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @prasad.surase could you show your solution in code. I'm having a similar issue. My modal pops up but it contains all of the images in my bootstrap grid - they are being retrieved from a database using this:      <% directors.each do |video| %>
         <%= image_tag(video.video_url, data: {toggle: "myModal", target: "#myModal", :id => video.id }) %>
         <% end %>

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland its because u have added the loop inside the modal. move the code to create modal inside the loop. So, if u have 5 images, u will have 5 different modal popups. Now, each link need the id of the modal, so that when you click the link, the modal pops up. So, when creating the links, generate unique ids and assign each id to the modal and link that modal popup to the link. This way, when u click the link, its associated popup will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Is you main goal to display a larger version of the photo in a pop-up or pop-over window? If so, you may be better off using a "lightbox" type solution. They are straightforward to implement, and work great with Rails.

Here are some options to get you started:

- [Lightbox 2](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
- [Nivo Lightbox](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-lightbox/)
- [Lightbox for Bootstrap 3](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/)

If you *do* actually want to render dynamic content into a Bootstrap modal, you need to do a few additional things:

1. Add a "data-toggle" and "data-target" attribute to your anchor (link).
2. Create a modal "template" on the same page that Bootstrap will unhide and inject your dynamic content in to, using the matching "ID" tag specified in your "data-target" attribute
3. Add a "modal" function in your controller, which rails will call to get the dynamic data and add to your "modal.html.erb" view, which is what is injected into the Bootstrap modal template

If you is what you want to do, I can provide a specific example of working code.